# problems with R folder and library

Tags: java, android, build, import

I tried to import this library: https://github.com/Eaiman/BitmapHandler into my android project.

However, when I import it, my project got lots of errors with android.support.v4.app library. I hovered the problem and fixed it with the option "Add project 'BitmapHandler' to build path of this project". It seemed ok to me and fixed my first problem.
But now I'm no longer able to reference my projects `R` folder. When I hover to fix the problem it asks me if I want to build the path of `R.android` but that's not what I want, I just want to reference my own R folder to the images I have.

How can I solve this problem? Thank you very much for your attention

Comment: If you have this problem on your R folder, it means, project could not be built. I thing it should be about lib. Could you please share your logcat ?

Comment: what android API version you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to place the library, which you would like to import, in the subdirectory 'libs' of your android project.

Your settings should look like this:

[image]

[image]

Important is  to select 'Android Private Libraries' aswell as 'Android Dependencies'. The IDE will do everything else in order to import your library.

Note: You may have to restart Eclipse in order to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the same `android.support.v4.app` library for your library and in your project. Otherwise it will show mismatch errors.